# Sumifs in VBA with multiple criteria in one column

Tags: vba, sumifs

How to sum up year 2011 to 2016 with filter "Company" as AAA * CCC; filter "Include or not" as 1; LOB as EC & PL in VBA coding?

```
n1 = Application.CountA(company)
n2 = Application.CountA(LOB)
prem = 0
For j = 1 To n2
    For i = 1 To n1
        Worksheets("Data_Premium").Activate
        prem = prem + Application.SumIfs(Range("$E:$E"), Range("$A:$A"), company(i), Range("$D:$D"), 1, Range("$C:$C"), LOB(j))
    Next i
Next j
```

i wanted to use a For loop, but it shows "script out of range". Take 2011 as an example
[image]

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck or errors? Please see [ask] and [No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/).

Comment: i wanted to use a for loop
    n1 = Application.CountA(company)n2 = Application.CountA(LOB)
    prem = 0
    For j = 1 To n2
        For i = 1 To n1
            Worksheets("Data_Premium").Activate
            prem = prem + Application.SumIfs(Range("$E:$E"), Range("$A:$A"), company(i), Range("$D:$D"), 1, Range("$C:$C"), LOB(j))
        Next i
    Next j

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use formula-array, like this: `={SUM(IF($C$2:$C$5=1, $D$2:$I$5, 0))}`, where

`$C$2:$C$5` - is the range under 'Include in calculation' header,

`$E$2:$I$5` - is the range under `2011` - `2016` headers,

How to use formula-array? See: [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7)